# Django 4.1 not identifying static file

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I'm a beginner with Django and have been working a small project that requires quite a bit of styling. However, for some reason, Django isn't picking up on my static css file.

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path

TEMPLATES_DIR = Path(BASE_DIR) / 'templates'
STATIC_DIR = Path(BASE_DIR) / 'static'

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'CalculatorApp'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Calculator.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Calculator.wsgi.application'

...

STATIC_ROOT = Path(BASE_DIR) / 'static'
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILE_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

I double checked my spelling, settings.py directory, checked countless posts and can't seem to find a solution. This is my first time using stack overflow, so I'm assuming I just upload pictures of my code.

Edit: here are is my views.py and urls.py.

```
# Urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from CalculatorApp import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]


# Views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Are you using any web server or using development server ?

Comment: development sever.

Comment: Show the view part too. Where are you storing your css file ? Have a look at this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial06/

Comment: I will take a look at that link. In the mean time, I have also posted my view.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development